# How to check input box is empty by v-model in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my learning app about Vue, I bind `message` with the input box using `v-model` of vue. In that, I set another method to check if the input box is empty then I set default `message` value to something else by default.

This below is my snippet:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  },
  methods:{
   check:function(){
    if (this.message==''){
     this.message='Please enter text in text box below';
    }
   }
  }
})
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <!--
        v-model:
        Used with form input for user synchronize data between front-end and back-end
        as seen here message is bind with form input, so whenver we update the form, the var message
        will be updated as well
     -->
        <div id="app">
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
            <input v-model="message" v-on="check">
        </div>
        
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

However, it seemed like `v-on="check"` does not work as well as the input box is empty the `message` does not change. Is there anything I was missing?

PS: I am new to VueJS :)

Comment: you have a syntax error - there needs to be something after `v-on`, for instance `v-on:click` or `v-on:input` will trigger onClick and onInput respectively. Currently you're not binding v-on to any DOM event

Comment: @KyurikoTea, yeah it is, by `v-on:input="check"` or `v-on:keyup="check"` it works but the input box is never empty. Thanks. :)

Comment: I'm confused, pardon my poor English - did `v-on:input="check"` or `v-on:keyup="check"` solve your problem? Because I binded with either of these two events and it worked for me. If you're trying to achieve something else, please do update your snippets.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue like:

1. Add conditional logic to your template:

```html
<p>{{ message || 'Your default text here'}}</p>
```

2. Use [computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) property
3. Use [filter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html)

Answer (score 0):

Test it Like this:

```
if (this.message === '' || this.message === null || this.message.value === 0){
            this.message='Please enter text in text box below';
        }
```